# Subdivision surface is different

Tags: subdivision-surface

Hi guys I'm new to blender, I just following the tutorial。 and my modifier just show the different results after i enter edit mode. How to solve this problem? thanks ! [image]

[image]

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81340/curved-mesh-topology-2/81346#81346

Comment: to help, you could have linked (or cited some relevant info from) the tutorial...

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77925/what-is-the-box-that-appears-around-this-mesh-in-edit-mode and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9144/hide-subsurf-modifier-curve-in-edit-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or Apply your Subdivision.

Until you hit "Apply", it's just a previz of the subdivision that you COULD get.

When rendering, it doesn't matter but the best practice would be to apply all your subdiv before final rendering...

Comment: The 'best practice' is not to apply modifiers unless necessary and there is no need to apply before rendering.

Answer (score -1):

disable this icon right here :D

[image: Sub Div Surface Modifier]